Python dask ValueError: unrecognized chunk manager dask - must be one of: []
I am using xarray to concatenate multiple netcdf files using xarray.open_mfdataset. However, I get the following error when I attempt to run my code:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[21], line 1
----> 1 ds = xarray.open_mfdataset('oisst_*.nc', combine="nested", concat_dim="time")

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py:1056, in open_mfdataset(paths, chunks, concat_dim, compat, preprocess, engine, data_vars, coords, combine, parallel, join, attrs_file, combine_attrs, **kwargs)
   1053     open_ = open_dataset
   1054     getattr_ = getattr
-> 1056 datasets = [open_(p, **open_kwargs) for p in paths]
   1057 closers = [getattr_(ds, "_close") for ds in datasets]
   1058 if preprocess is not None:

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py:1056, in <listcomp>(.0)
   1053     open_ = open_dataset
   1054     getattr_ = getattr
-> 1056 datasets = [open_(p, **open_kwargs) for p in paths]
   1057 closers = [getattr_(ds, "_close") for ds in datasets]
   1058 if preprocess is not None:

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py:579, in open_dataset(filename_or_obj, engine, chunks, cache, decode_cf, mask_and_scale, decode_times, decode_timedelta, use_cftime, concat_characters, decode_coords, drop_variables, inline_array, chunked_array_type, from_array_kwargs, backend_kwargs, **kwargs)
    572 overwrite_encoded_chunks = kwargs.pop("overwrite_encoded_chunks", None)
    573 backend_ds = backend.open_dataset(
    574     filename_or_obj,
    575     drop_variables=drop_variables,
    576     **decoders,
    577     **kwargs,
    578 )
--> 579 ds = _dataset_from_backend_dataset(
    580     backend_ds,
    581     filename_or_obj,
    582     engine,
    583     chunks,
    584     cache,
    585     overwrite_encoded_chunks,
    586     inline_array,
    587     chunked_array_type,
    588     from_array_kwargs,
    589     drop_variables=drop_variables,
    590     **decoders,
    591     **kwargs,
    592 )
    593 return ds

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py:372, in _dataset_from_backend_dataset(backend_ds, filename_or_obj, engine, chunks, cache, overwrite_encoded_chunks, inline_array, chunked_array_type, from_array_kwargs, **extra_tokens)
    370     ds = backend_ds
    371 else:
--> 372     ds = _chunk_ds(
    373         backend_ds,
    374         filename_or_obj,
    375         engine,
    376         chunks,
    377         overwrite_encoded_chunks,
    378         inline_array,
    379         chunked_array_type,
    380         from_array_kwargs,
    381         **extra_tokens,
    382     )
    384 ds.set_close(backend_ds._close)
    386 # Ensure source filename always stored in dataset object

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/backends/api.py:320, in _chunk_ds(backend_ds, filename_or_obj, engine, chunks, overwrite_encoded_chunks, inline_array, chunked_array_type, from_array_kwargs, **extra_tokens)
    309 def _chunk_ds(
    310     backend_ds,
    311     filename_or_obj,
   (...)
    318     **extra_tokens,
    319 ):
--> 320     chunkmanager = guess_chunkmanager(chunked_array_type)
    322     # TODO refactor to move this dask-specific logic inside the DaskManager class
    323     if isinstance(chunkmanager, DaskManager):

File ~/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/site-packages/xarray/namedarray/parallelcompat.py:110, in guess_chunkmanager(manager)
    108 if isinstance(manager, str):
    109     if manager not in chunkmanagers:
--> 110         raise ValueError(
    111             f"unrecognized chunk manager {manager} - must be one of: {list(chunkmanagers)}"
    112         )
    114     return chunkmanagers[manager]
    115 elif isinstance(manager, ChunkManagerEntrypoint):
    116     # already a valid ChunkManager so just pass through

ValueError: unrecognized chunk manager dask - must be one of: []

I'm using the following code:
import netCDF4
import numpy
import xarray

ds = xarray.open_mfdataset('oisst_*.nc', combine="nested", concat_dim="time")

I'm referring this medium page for this code.
I've already tried this existing method. I downgraded xarray to 2022.11.0 and then to 0.21.1 as OP suggested, reinstalled dask and upgraded xarray back to 2024.2.0 but found no success with the issue.
My current versions for xarray and dask are:
INSTALLED VERSIONS
------------------
commit: None
python: 3.10.10 (main, Mar 21 2023, 13:41:39) [Clang 14.0.6 ]
python-bits: 64
OS: Darwin
OS-release: 23.4.0
machine: x86_64
processor: i386
byteorder: little
LC_ALL: None
LANG: None
LOCALE: (None, 'UTF-8')
libhdf5: 1.12.2
libnetcdf: 4.9.3-development

xarray: 2024.2.0
pandas: 1.5.3
numpy: 1.23.5
scipy: 1.10.1
netCDF4: 1.6.5
pydap: None
h5netcdf: None
h5py: 3.8.0
Nio: None
zarr: None
cftime: 1.6.3
nc_time_axis: None
iris: None
bottleneck: None
dask: 2024.4.1
distributed: None
matplotlib: 3.7.1
cartopy: None
seaborn: 0.12.2
numbagg: None
fsspec: 2024.3.1
cupy: None
pint: None
sparse: None
flox: None
numpy_groupies: None
setuptools: 69.1.1
pip: 24.0
conda: 23.3.1
pytest: None
mypy: None
IPython: 8.12.0
sphinx: None

